# Is it possible to customize style of bootstrap $modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

In my application I am using bootstrap `$modal` popup two different times. content of both pop-ups is different hence size of both pop-up must be also different. I tried to style `$modal`  using

```
.modal {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 60%;
    height: 88%;
    width: 28%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:auto;
    border-radius: 0px;
}
```

but as expected it is changing style of both of my pop-ups. Is there any way to apply different class to each popup?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide more details for your question ? the html code where you are using modal for instance. Or maybe a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Joseph it is more of a general question not problem specific. if i have two modals in one project. can i have two different widths and heights for them? if possible how?

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe You can do it with adding extra class to the modal right? or Do you expect any other results?

Comment: @SurjithSM how do i add extra class to bootstrap modal?

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe Do you have access to HTML? Then you can do it like `<div class="modal newstyle">` then you can style it like `.modal.newstyle` Am I missing something?

Comment: @SurjithSM I'll try and let you know, or if u know the answer can u make a simple fiddle for it so i will accept your answer and assign you bounty

Comment: doesn't your modal have an Id? Just overwrite the styles per Id

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you have access to HTML, Then you can add an extra class to the modal like `<div class="modal custom">` then you can style it like `.modal.custom`. Full example below

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/ka8uW/)**

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
  Variable Modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal custom fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
   ....
```

**CSS**

```
.modal.custom .modal-dialog {
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
    /*add what you want here*/
}
```

Let me know if you have further issues in the comments.

Comment: looks like a copy paste from http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals , which did not work for me for unknown reason

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe Yes it is, But I've customized for your needs. Is that working for you?

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe Can you tell me what are your findings on my fiddle that makes didn't work for you?

Comment: In my Application if i remove width from .modal class. it gets some default width (543 px) and i am not setting it from anywhere.

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe You don't need to remove width, just change width for the extra class.

Comment: Nope, not working, that width is coming from                  bootstrap-combined.min.css file

Comment: can you check my solution and see if it is ok to use it

Comment: yes your code is working, not in my project but everywhere else!

Comment: @AdityaPonkshe Hmm.. there may be some underlying issue

Answer (score 2):

**Update 2017 - Bootstrap 4**

The structure of the modal has changed since Bootstrap 3, so now different CSS is required to customize the position, size or modal styles. To change the modal width, set the `max-width` on the `modal-dialog`, for exmaple:

```
.modal.custom .modal-dialog {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

[Custom modal demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/6crUUkT8DU/bootstrap-4-custom-modals)

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, modals will automatically change size depending on the size of the content within them. If that's all you need, BS does it for you...

If you want to style each modal independently, you want to use an `id` tag in addition to the class `modal` tags. You can reference this `id` in your CSS with a `#`.

e.g.

```
#modalblue {
  background-color:blue;
}
#modalgreen {
  background-color:green;
}
```

and the corresponding markup is

```
<div class="modal" some-other-attributes id="modalblue">
  ...modal content
</div>
<div class="modal" some-other-attributes id="modalgreen">
  ...modal content
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include a minimum working example of this? Perhaps the stylesheet isn't linked properly, or there is some other more mysterious issue in play.

Comment: it is not working because i am not assigning .modal class to the bootstrap. it is default, so if you can tell me how to assign ID to the bootstrap modal your method will work.

Comment: Using ids to apply styling in CSS [is an antipattern](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6sAm7CLoCQ).

Answer (score 0):

You can see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) that you can give an id for each and every modal you are making.
Here is an example:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#green-modal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="green-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modal #2

```
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#red-modal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="red-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now you can easily target your css using thos id's. E.g.

```
#green-modal { background-color: #00FF00; }
#red-modal { background-color: #FF0000; }
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <div id="addtaskmodal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="width:80%;left:30%;right:30%;top:5%;bottom:5%; position:fixed; overflow:hidden;" >
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3>New Task</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="max-height:500px;" >
                <p>My modal content here…</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="startnow" onClick="createNewTask('start')" >Start
                now</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="createNewTask('')" >Save</button>
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="addclientmodal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" >
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h3>New Task</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="max-height:500px;" >
                <p>My modal content here…</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"  onclick="saveNewClient()" >Save</button>
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              </div>
            </div>
```

here i have two modal windows ,load the contents dynamically by ajax,i had inline style for modal popup , also you can add css style by referring the #id

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the answers given by other users. None of them worked for me. 
I found a way on my own, many will say it's not a correct method but it is working for me.

I just called a javascript function where I am setting style for .modal

```
function changeCSS(){

setTimeout(function(){

    var allModals = document.getElementsByClassName('modal');
        for (var i = 0; i < allModals.length; i++) {

            console.log(allModals[i]);
            allModals[i].style.width="60%";
        }
    },1500);
}
```

If anyone finds a better way to do this please answer this question I'll surely try it and assign you the bounty if it works.

Comment: So you want to make all width 60%. right? You can simply do it with custom CSS. like `.modal { width:60% }`

Comment: that will make all modals change

Comment: yes, as you said, it's not a correct way to do it. you can stick to css with no javascript. Unless you use the same data-target, you must be able to have different width. If you use the same data-target to achieve different width, it's better to re-think your strategy.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you use the developer console (depending on which browser you are using), you will find that directly styling the ".modal" class doesn't affect the modals as the main styling can be found in the classes applied to the modal's sub elements. (e.g .modal-dialog, .modal-content). In your case, what you should do is:

```css
.modal-content{
    border-radius: 0;
    background-clip: border-box;
    min-height: 400px;
        min-width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Did you want to show something when the Run code snippet button was pressed or where you just trying to show a code block?

Comment: Sorry i made i mistake . Corrected... thanks to pointing me towards that