# Add style to bootstrap modal content div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a form that loads content from a checkbox menu.

If a user checks a box, a bootstrap v3.3.4 modal pops and the chosen content shows up in the modal.

Here is the code when the modal is closed:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">My Modal Title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="box">MY CONTENT IS HERE</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">Footer text is here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the modal is opened, a style is being added to `<div class="box">`
like this: `<div class="box" style="display: block;">`

I'd really like to add more styles to that div, but only when the modal is open. From where does the style get added? I've checked my jquery.js and bootstrap.js files and can't figure it out. Also tried various if statements to no avail. i.e. `$('#myModal').is(':visible');`

Thanks so much for any advice.

Comment: Just whack it in your CSS, providing the rules are after Bootstrap CSS is called, your CSS will overwrite them. As (presumably) the modal would be display:none, you could probably add the rules in to the modal without them being seen until active.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854035/is-it-possible-to-customize-style-of-bootstrap-modal

Comment: If `.box` is not visible at first, can't you just add your styles to it in your CSS? `.box { /* Styles */ }`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to check if a modal is opened or not is to check if the modalElement has the class `'in'` appended to it when the modal is opened.

```
$('#myModal').hasClass('in')
```

Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1151/

Comment: Thx! One more question. 
In the code below, the box div that is styled with display:block is the portion that displays in the modal. I want it to be checked. I don't want the other input, the one not displayed, to be checked. Is this possible?
    `$(document).ready(function(){  
     if ($('#myModal').hasClass('in')); {  
        $(".checkthis").prop("checked", "true");  
     }  
    });  
    <div class="box" style="display:block;">  
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkthis".....>  
    </div>  
    <div class="box">  
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkthis"...>  
    </div>`

Comment: You can certainly do it but for that you don't need to check if the modal is opened or not. You can simply intercept it while opening the modal http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1152/

Comment: Thank you! Hmm, it seems the second box still gets checked even though I did not add it to the modal. Optimally the second checkbox should remain unchecked...I've updated the fiddle here, to illustrate. Thx a bunch. 
http://jsfiddle.net/3kgbG/1159/